# How can I use javascript to check if a sharepoint list contains a specific word, when he is already have information

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

on my site I have list with column. One like "Status"(Choice column. Drop down menu) and when user change this column on Finished need alert him.

HTML code of list and JQuery code (Past on Script Editor on WepPart)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".ms-formbody").blur(function() {
        var Text = $(this).val();
        
        if (Text == "Finished") {
            alert("Alert");
        } 

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr>
    <td width="113" class="ms-formlabel" nowrap="true" valign="top">
      <span class="ms-h3 ms-standardheader" id="Status">
      <nobr>Status
          <span title="This is a required field." class="ms-accentText"> *</span> 
        </nobr>
       </span>
    </td>
    <td width="350" class="ms-formbody" valign="top">
      <!-- FieldName="Status"
    FieldInternalName="Status"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
      <span dir="none">
        <select title="Status Required Field" class="ms-RadioText" id="Status_30b2ab26-c1c0-48fd-b190-854b32fe67ca_$DropDownChoice">
            <option value="Planned">Planned</option>
            <option value="Development">Development</option>
            <option value="Executing">Executing</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="Finished">Finished</option>
            <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
        </select>
        <br>
      </span>

      <span class="ms-metadata">Choice</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: and what's wrong with your current code exactly? How does the user change the status? I see no input fields or dropdown lists or anything.

Comment: when user was changed their choice, and has clicked to detailed view, and when page did load, script will check, column "Status" has "Finished", then user will alert. I Hope I had explain exactly

Comment: That's what you want it to do, or what it does now? Again, I see no evidence of any of the functionality you describe. I can't even see the dropdown you're referring to. Have you written any code for it yet? What issue are you facing, apart from simply not having started your work?

Comment: what is? Please edit your question. Don't add code to the comments, if that's what you were planning to do. Show it in context.

Comment: That's doesn't work how i need. When i change status on finished, alert not show.

Comment: What doesn't? You _still_ haven't shown me anything meaningful. There's no HTML in your code which would ever match the selector `$(".ms-formlabel .ms-standardheader .ms-link:visited")` in your jQuery, so the code would never run, according to your example. There's no element with the class .ms-link, in particular. It's trivial to see that from looking at the HTML for two seconds. The word "Finished" appears only within a `<td>` whose class is `ms-formbody`, again it's trivial to see that.

Comment: And there's no sign of the dropdownlist you keep mentioning. It's not clear how the user can actually change anything in this page - there are no interactive elements, only some static table cells. There's nothing which would activate a "blur" function. Can you see why I don't understand what you're trying to do? Your code and your HTML just don't even match up, not even close. And they don't match up to what your'e describing either. perhaps you posted the wrong HTML. It's hard to help until the question actually makes sense.

Comment: Lastly, if there really _is_ a dropdownlist (a `<select` element normally, in HTML) somewhere on your page, then if you want to detect that the user has changed the selected value, you'd use the "change" event, not blur - blur only happens when the user moves focus away from the control, which they may or may not do, you can't rely on that. And dropdownlists have options with values inside them, not just plain text, so you'd need to check the selected `value` of the element, not its text.

Comment: I was edit my HTML and Script code. There have <select>. I need this alert, when user already created their list, with any status (not a "finished") but when he is change, user must be alert

Comment: I changed it now so we can actually read it properly, but thanks. "I need this alert, when user already created their list, with any status (not a "finished") but when he is change, user must be alert"...this is not what you asked for originally. Please make your mind up.

Comment: Anyway I have added an answer which hopefully helps you, even if it doesn't exactly match whatever your current requirement is about when the alert should display.

Comment: yea. I am sorry. This is my final question

Comment: you should edit the question then, to show what you actually want now. Potentially if my answer doesn't exactly reflect what you need then I can edit it, if the requirement is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a few issues here:

1) you're selecting completely the wrong element in the jQuery. Currently it will match a `<td` element, but that doesn't have any change or blur events, and it doesn't have a value either. You need to get hold of the dropdownlist in order to detect when it's changed. Given the HTML below, you can use the `ms-RadioText` class which the `<select` has got.

2) "blur" is the wrong event to handle - this will only occur if the user moves the focus away from the dropdown after they selected a value. You can't rely on this actually happening. "change" is the correct event.

3) Your exact requirement for what should occur when the select changes is unclear and appears (from the comments) to have changed since the question was posted, so I'm going to give an example where it simply reports the newly selected value in all scenarios. If you want to do something more specific than that, you can easily add an `if` statement or whatever you need.

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".ms-RadioText").change(function() {
        var Text = $(this).val();
        alert(Text);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr>
    <td width="113" class="ms-formlabel" nowrap="true" valign="top">
      <span class="ms-h3 ms-standardheader" id="Status">
      <nobr>Status
          <span title="This is a required field." class="ms-accentText"> *</span> 
        </nobr>
       </span>
    </td>
    <td width="350" class="ms-formbody" valign="top">
      <!-- FieldName="Status"
    FieldInternalName="Status"
    FieldType="SPFieldChoice"
    -->
      <span dir="none">
        <select title="Status Required Field" class="ms-RadioText" id="Status_30b2ab26-c1c0-48fd-b190-854b32fe67ca_$DropDownChoice">
            <option value="Planned">Planned</option>
            <option value="Development">Development</option>
            <option value="Executing">Executing</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="Finished">Finished</option>
            <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
        </select>
        <br>
      </span>

      <span class="ms-metadata">Choice</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you. I achieved what I wanted with ur code, but slightly changing it(if action)

Comment: No problem. In that case please remember to mark the answer as "accepted" (click the tick mark next to the question so it turns green) - thankyou. I hope the explanation also clarified to you where you were going wrong. I think you perhaps need to get a clearer understanding of jQuery and selectors and what they mean.

Comment: One more question. How I can clarify that alert must will show only on "Status" column. With ID="..."? Because I have a lot of columns with ms-RadioText classes and naturally alert had shows in all.

Comment: yes, with the ID: `$("#Status_30b2ab26-c1c0-48fd-b190-854b32fe67ca_$DropDownChoice").change` - I hope that Sharepoint generates the same ID each time for the element. If not your other option is an attribute selector based on the "title" attribute, but of course it's just a label so still someone might change it in future.

Answer (score -1):

Use the code below to achieve it.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[title='Status Required Field']").change(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="Finished"){
            alert("Alert");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: I has paste this to web part(Script Editor) on page "New Item" on list. And this doesn't work. No alert, when i change status on finished. And yet, i need this alert, when user already created their list, with any status (not a "finished") but when he is change, user must be alert

Comment: I suggest you use title to select the element in jQuery code, I modify the code to make it works. In my test the "Status" column is not a required field. If it is a required field, we need use $("select[title='Status Required Field']").